# Footer in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

My footer is in the middle of the page - I am extremely new to coding and just doing a really basic website for a class. My footer is okay on my other pages, but this page has a form, so I'm not sure if that's affecting it somehow?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: century gothic;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

header {
  background: #000000;
  height: 125px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  /*this option by default dispose the elements in a row (flex-direction: row)*/
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*when I specify 2 values to margin, the first one is for the top and bottom side, the second for the left and right side*/
  margin: 0 1vw;
}


}

}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: century gothic;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
form {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 75px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  text-align: left;
  display: in-line block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.submitbutton {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 80px;
  display: block;
}
input[type=submit] {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: in-line block;
}
.carimg {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}
footer {
  background: #000000;
  height: 125px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.footerlinks {
  float: left;
  word-spacing: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.contactinfo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.sociallinks {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <Title>Collision Guru</Title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <!-- list item one -->
        <li>
          <a href="auto2.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <!-- list item two -->
        <li>
          <a href="aboutauto2.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <!-- list item three -->
        <li>
          <a href="service3.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <!-- list item four -->
        <li>
          <a>Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="CG1.svg" alt-text="Collision Guru Logo" width=250px height=80px class="center">
  </header>
  <h1> Contact Us</h1>
  <img src="yellow car headlight collision.jpg" width=450px height=400px class="carimg">
  <form>
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"> <br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
    <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="option1" value="Paint">
    <label for="option1"> Paint Job</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option2" name="option2" value="Body">
    <label for="option2"> Body Work</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option3" name="option3" value="Clean">
    <label for="option3"> Cleaning</label><br>
    <div class="submitbutton">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>

  </form>


  <footer>
    <nav>
      <div class="contactinfo">
        440-555-6893 • mike.tarescavage@gmail.com
      </div>
      <div class="sociallinks">
        <img src="facebook-icon.png" width=30px height=30px> <img src="IG-icon-2.png" width=30px height=30px>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Again, I'm very new, so sorry if anything looks crazy. Any response within the next few days would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Websites are not pieces of paper. They don't need footers.

Answer (score 3):

When float the image and form left and right, wrap them into a container will be better.

I added a `form-container` and set `overflow: hidden;`. You may specify its size. See if this i swhat you want.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: century gothic;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

header {
  background: #000000;
  height: 125px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  /*this option by default dispose the elements in a row (flex-direction: row)*/
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*when I specify 2 values to margin, the first one is for the top and bottom side, the second for the left and right side*/
  margin: 0 1vw;
}


}

}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: century gothic;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
.form-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
form {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 75px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  text-align: left;
  display: in-line block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.submitbutton {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 80px;
  display: block;
}
input[type=submit] {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: in-line block;
}
.carimg {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}
footer {
  background: #000000;
  height: 125px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.footerlinks {
  float: left;
  word-spacing: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.contactinfo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.sociallinks {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <Title>Collision Guru</Title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <!-- list item one -->
        <li>
          <a href="auto2.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <!-- list item two -->
        <li>
          <a href="aboutauto2.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <!-- list item three -->
        <li>
          <a href="service3.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <!-- list item four -->
        <li>
          <a>Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="CG1.svg" alt-text="Collision Guru Logo" width=250px height=80px class="center">
  </header>
  <h1> Contact Us</h1>
  <div class="form-container">
    <img src="yellow car headlight collision.jpg" width=450px height=400px class="carimg">
    <form>
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"> <br>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
      <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
      <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="option1" value="Paint">
      <label for="option1"> Paint Job</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option2" name="option2" value="Body">
      <label for="option2"> Body Work</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option3" name="option3" value="Clean">
      <label for="option3"> Cleaning</label><br>
      <div class="submitbutton">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>


  <footer>
    <nav>
      <div class="contactinfo">
        440-555-6893 • mike.tarescavage@gmail.com
      </div>
      <div class="sociallinks">
        <img src="facebook-icon.png" width=30px height=30px> <img src="IG-icon-2.png" width=30px height=30px>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that worked, but now the image in my header is moving around - any ideas on that?